# Parsing PostgreSQL data into Highcharts chart objects correctly

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, parsing

I'm trying to fetch timeserie data from PostgreSQL & after successful queries and parsing of data, I have some problem in indexing it. This mistake is probably quite small, but I just cant find it.

After I get data from PostgreSQL, it looks like this:

```
[
     { id: 2,
       time: 2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z,
       value: 0.311303124694538
     },
     { id: 2,
       time: 2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z,
       value: 0.13233108292117
    },
    { id: 3,
      time: 2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z,
      value: 0.13233108292117 }
]
```

After this step I'm reducing data by id:

```
    let results = sqlresult.rows.reduce(function(results, row) {
        (results[row.id] = results[row.id] || []).push([row.time,row.value]);
        return results;
    }, {})

    let clonedObj = { ...results };
```

After this step data is formatted like in below:

```
{ '2':
   [ [ 2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z, 0.311303124694538 ],
     [ 2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z, 0.13233108292117 ],
     [ 2019-09-12T03:36:02.432Z, 0.171794173529729 ]
  ]
}
```

But once I'm about to drop it into Highchart it won't work. My problem is probably that I didn't fully understand how does that reduce function work and now I'm trying to copy it. If some of you could show me how to avoid this step and to do all in data reduce step, I'd be thankful.

```
    for(let i=0; i< Object.keys(clonedObj).length; i++){

          highchart[i] = {
            name: Object.keys(clonedObj)[i],
            data: clonedObj[i]
          }
    }
```

I'm expecting result like this below:

```
[{"name":1,"data":[["2019-09-12T03:36:00.433Z",20],["2019-09-12T03:35:38.433Z",-20]]},{"name":2,"data":[["2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z",0.311303124694538]}]]
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that I have been too long time next to my pc.

In that last function I need to index data by this clonedObj[Object.keys(clonedObj)[i]].

However, if there is still better solutions to optimize this code - I'd be glad to know, now I don't think it's as efficient as it could be.

Comment: Hi @sukkis, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 2):

From your nicely formatted data listings, it looks like you're using Postgres to package rows of data already. This is something I do all the time, but without some pretty narrow limits. I'd like to get better at this, so I figured I'd give your question a bit of time. To start with, I created a table named "reading" with your data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reading (
    id integer,
    "time" text,
    "value" real
);
```

I get back a listing like your top one with this query:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(reading_row))) as reading_object
  from (select id, time, value from reading) as reading_row
```

Your target output example doesn't parse right for me, I think you're after this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":1,
      "data":[ 
         [ 
            "2019-09-12T03:36:00.433Z",
            20
         ],
         [ 
            "2019-09-12T03:35:38.433Z",
            -20
         ]
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":2,
      "data":[ 
         "2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z",
         0.311303124694538
      ]
   }
]
```

Fair warning: Yeah, I don't really know how to do that, and I'm hoping someone answers with a simple script to generate exactly the format you want on the Postgres side. But I made a start. Check this out:

```
select id, json_object_agg(time, value order by time)
from reading
group by id
```

Here's what I get:

```
2   "{ ""2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z"" : 0.132331, ""2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z"" : 0.311303 }"
3   "{ ""2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z"" : 0.132331 }"
```

Here's something that's...not right..but getting closer:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(reading_row))) as reading_object
  from (
        select id, json_object_agg(time, value order by time) as data
        from reading
        group by id
    ) as reading_row
```

Which returns:

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":2,
      "data":{ 
         "2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z":0.132331,
         "2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z":0.311303
      }
   },
   { 
      "id":3,
      "data":{ 
         "2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z":0.132331
      }
   }
]
```

I took another crack at it here, this might be what you're after, or close. I noticed you're renaming 'id' as 'name', so that's in the final query:

```
 select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(subquery)))
    from (
  select id as name, 
         array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('time', time, 'value', value))) as data
    from reading
 group by id
   ) subquery
```

The output, pretty-printed, looks like this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":2,
      "data":[ 
         { 
            "time":"2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z",
            "value":0.311303
         },
         { 
            "time":"2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z",
            "value":0.132331
         }
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":3,
      "data":[ 
         { 
            "time":"2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z",
            "value":0.132331
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This variant has the same structure, but without labels on the elements within the array:

select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(subquery)))
    from (
          select id as name, 
                 array_to_json(array_agg(array[time, value::text])) as data
            from reading
group by id
   ) subquery

Apart from the numeric value being cast as text, I think this is what you asked for:

```
 select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(subquery)))
    from (
          select id as name, 
                 array_to_json(array_agg(array[time, value::text])) as data
            from reading
group by id
   ) subquery

[ 
   { 
      "name":2,
      "data":[ 
         [ 
            "2019-09-12T03:36:04.433Z",
            "0.311303"
         ],
         [ 
            "2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z",
            "0.132331"
         ]
      ]
   },
   { 
      "name":3,
      "data":[ 
         [ 
            "2019-09-12T03:36:03.434Z",
            "0.132331"
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

Note: I don't see where you're getting your output of 20, -20 in your example.

Between array_to_json(), row(), array_agg(), and json_build_object(), it looks like you can get most any format you need.

Here's hoping that someone who actually knows what they're doing chimes in.